# Firebase Data Retrieval (2.4 version)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have already posted a question about this, but have struggled to get why nothing is showing up. I have gotten my Firebase data to save.

I'm trying to make a simple page where you type in a name and age and it saves that to Firebase then in a section below, it displays this information.

Here is what I have for my code: the function `addFB()` is the `onclick` function for when a button is pressed:

```
rootRef = new Firebase('https://addview-c21e6.firebaseio.com');

function addFB() {
  var usersRef = rootRef.child('users');
  var userName = document.getElementById('userName'),
      userAge = document.getElementById('userAge');
  var user = usersRef.child(userName.value).set({

    Name: userName.value,
    Age: userAge.value

  });
  userName.value = '';
  userAge.value = '';

  showData =  document.getElementById('showData');
  var firebaseDataRef = new Firebase('https://addview-c21e6.firebaseio.com/users');
  firebaseDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    showData.innerText = console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to do. Are you wanting the user to click the button which writes the data to Firebase and then immediately read back the data from Firebase and display it? If so, that code isn't going to work (well). You need to give Firebase time to write the data so a read would need to occur *after* the data is written. With the code you have the read will occur before Firebase has a chance to complete the write block. (code is faster than the internet)

Comment: Jay, I appreciate the help. Yes, that's essentially it. I want the user to be able to click the button which puts the data into firebase. The idea is to be able to submit the names and have it show up below in a view section. So are you saying I need to just put it later on in the code?

Comment: Not later in the code, rather later in the code *execution*. Let me preface this; there may be something else going on as well, but if you look at your code snippet, .set writes the data to Firebase and then code-wise the data is immediately read. That situation doesn't allow for the asynchronous nature of Firebase. There is a lag to any read or write and the code following that .set executes way before the data has a chance to be written. If you want to read back data, wait for it to be written. That can be achieved via a [Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data).